# PHP JSON encode. Echo value

Tags: php, json

I need to echo the value of "summary"

```
    {  
   "expand":"names",
   "startAt":0,
   "maxResults":50,
   "total":1,
   "issues":[  
      {  
         "expand":"example",
         "id":"129018",
         "self":"https://example.com",
         "key":"914",
         "fields":{  
            "summary":"Hello there"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

The below code does not work:

```
$array_result = json_decode($run_curl, true);
    $title = $array_result['issues']['fields']['summary];
```

What am I doing wrong here? I am pretty sure it's smth simple and obvious.

Comment: if `issues` is an array, shouldn't you give it an index? Maybe: `$title = $array_result['issues'][0]['fields']['summary];`

Comment: this is a object after json_decode, so you need to access it like object.

Comment: @FrayneKonok he passed true as second param to `json_decode`

Comment: u can miss the single quate in summary object

Comment: @kalrsson, check out me [at answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36588006/php-json-encode-echo-value/36588098#36588098).

Answer (score 2):

`issues` is an array, pass it an index like this:

`$title = $array_result['issues'][0]['fields']['summary'];`

Note the `[0]`.

Comment: @Pang oops, I c&p from OP's example, fixed now, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

> I miss something called `true` at `json_decode($json, true);`.
>
> If it is true then use: `echo $array_result[issues][0][fields][summary];`

[Online link](https://3v4l.org/etuuc), This is the online link where you can check it.

```
$json = '{  
   "expand":"names",
   "startAt":0,
   "maxResults":50,
   "total":1,
   "issues":[  
      {  
         "expand":"example",
         "id":"129018",
         "self":"https://example.com",
         "key":"914",
         "fields":{  
            "summary":"Hello there"
         }
      }
   ]
}';
```

**JSON Decode**

When you start using `json_decode`, this function makes some array as object, so to access array you need to use the `->` sign.

```
$array_result = json_decode($json);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array_result);
echo '</pre>';
echo $array_result->issues[0]->fields->summary;
```

**Output**

Decoded array:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [expand] => names
    [startAt] => 0
    [maxResults] => 50
    [total] => 1
    [issues] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [expand] => example
                    [id] => 129018
                    [self] => https://example.com
                    [key] => 914
                    [fields] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [summary] => Hello there
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

> Hello there

Answer (score 0):

issues is a list ,so you need to add key=0 to get the first element:

```
$title = $array_result['issues'][0]['fields']['summary'];
```